# Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist is longer than filepath buffer size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have this error in my application when I run, build the app, I have downloded both the google services android and ios files, but it is giving me this error abd (runner.app) is repeating and repeating inside the error! which is something very strange, I would really appreciate if you could tell me the solution.
here is the error:

> Failed to build iOS app Error (Xcode):
> '/Users/AccountName/Downloads/MyProject/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Ru
> nner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.
> app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/R
> unner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner
> .app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/
> Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
> is longer than filepath buffer size (1025).

Comment: Please rename all of the projects, folders, and files, including GoogleService-Info.plist, and ensure that all dependencies are updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
To fix this error, you can try the following:
```

- Move your project folder to a higher level directory.
- Rename your project folder to a shorter name.
- Rename the GoogleService-Info.plist file to a shorter name.
- Use a symbolic link to point to the GoogleService-Info.plist file from a shorter path.

```
If you are using Xcode, you can also try the following:

- In Xcode, select your project in the Project Navigator.
- Click the Runner target in the Project Navigator.
- In the Build Settings inspector, expand the Deployment section.
```

- Set the Product Name to a shorter name.
- Set the Bundle Identifier to a shorter name.
- Once you have made one of the above changes, clean and rebuild your project.

```
If you are still getting the error, you can try contacting Apple Support for further assistance.
```

- Here are some additional tips to avoid getting this error:
- Keep your project folder structure as shallow as possible.
- Use short and descriptive names for your project folders and files.
- Avoid using spaces in your project folder and file names.
- Use symbolic links to point to files from different locations.

I hope this helps!